# alternate colors/fonts etc in a text in reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

Would it be possible to alternate colors or fonts when writing a paragraph in a PDF with reportlab??

I am writing something like this :

```
p = ParagraphStyle('myStyle')
p.textColor = 'black'
p.fontSize = 10

pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
doc = canvas.Canvas('testDoc.pdf', landscape(A4))
txt = Paragraph(pages, p)
txt.wrapOn(doc,1200,1000)
txt.drawOn(doc, 0.5*inch, 6*inch)
```

The point of my question is: if I have good and bad pages, let' s say that pages 2,3 and 6,7 are bad ones, what I would like is to write them in red color for example and the rest in normal color. But I am afraid that this does not work like a table where you can set a style for each cell.

Then, is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you reviewed the [user guide?](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) You should be able to change the text color in a variety of ways. For instance, section 6.2 starts talking about paragraph markup and 6.3 deals with intra-paragraph markup. The "font" tag (demonstrated in figure 6.9) might be what you need.

Otherwise, I don't understand where the actual text is coming in. I would think you could change p.textColor for individual pages.

Comment: thanks mauve, I haven't read this guide, maybe it will help me, I will try